# QCanBusDevice Bufffer Flushing

Tags: c++, qt, buffer, flush, can-bus

I am creating a tool to parse CAN messages using PCAN Dongles connected to a micro controller. I am using the QCanBus library in Qt 5.10.

1. There are multiple CAN buses connected and I have a QThread for each to receive and parse the messages on QCanBusDevice::framesReceived signal.
2. Using PCAN View in parallel I can see that the changes in the CAN Data reported by the micro-controller don't get reflected instantly in my tool. It seems like the receive queue is still being emptied, i.e. my tool is not able to parse and store the CAN Message data as fast as the micro-controller is sending them.
3. I only have to concern myself with the latest value reported on CAN - if I try to print the payload of the message on qDebug(), I can see my tool parsing older data, which seems like it is still emptying the receive queue.

Is there any way to flush the receive queue without disconnecting QCanBusDevice?
If I disconnect and connect again, I am able to get the latest data which is on the wire.

Comment: So maybe check `framesAvailable()` before each `readFrame()`, and if there are too many then read them all without processing to clear the queue?

Comment: The problem is that the queue is protected and is part of QCanBusDevice library. They did't provide any API to flush or clear that QVector:
Here is the link: 
ReadFrame(): https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtserialbus/src/serialbus/qcanbusdevice.cpp.html#_ZN13QCanBusDevice9readFrameEv

There is a QVector incomingFrames which I can't flush unless I disconnect the device.

Comment: Calling `readFrame()` repeatedly and discarding the results is too slow?

Comment: Yes, since the amount of messages my microcontrollers is throwing out is huge - readFrame() can't keep up. The time delay between me getting the updated data exponentially grows.

Comment: On second thought, do you think I could literally copy & paste QCanBusDevice.cpp and QCanBusDevice.h files and make modifications?

Comment: That's a lot of traffic if a mutex lock and `takeFirst()` element from a vector causes slowdowns. Maybe try to make another thread in the middle that reads as fast as it can, so the `QCanBusDevice` don't need to `takeFirst()` from a long vector ever (usually `takeFirst()` from vector causes a copy of all its elements because the implementation has to slide them all to the beginning of the vector). About modifications: they can be made if the whole library is recompiled, there are probably other classes that inherit from `QCanBusDevice` and do the actual work.

Comment: @Velkan, I have a thread running which constantly tries to call readFrame(), however I think QVector is not the best implementation for this type of buffer. I am trying to recompile the source with modifications but that's a pain in itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clearFrames() has been included for Qt version 5.12. I had to build Qt from source with the changes I needed.